# Mathjax isn't working, how to fix it?

Tags: support, mathjax

I used win 7 and suddenly Mathjax doesn't work at https://math.stackexchange.com/ using

google chrome, firefox, ie9

It work at another site like this site.

**so how to fix it** ?

### [image: it is just show the tex command]

edit:
the error messag in java script at google chrome :
[image]

Comment: In Chrome, pressing Ctrl-Shift-J opens the JavaScript console. Any error messages there?

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills yes and Iam going to add it to the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a fest of browser-hijacking software on your computer. Google "Topic Torch", "clkmon" and so forth. I can't tell how or if this interferes with execution of MathJaX, but until the system is clean, non-working MathJax should be the least of your worries.

Comment: sry but I cant understand what exactly I need to do

Comment: @hammood There are step-by-step instructions on the [malware tips](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/) site: use "search malware" on the right. Or you can backup all your files and reinstall the operating system. Or ask for help from an experienced user/professional. In any case, the appropriate Q&A site for such issues is [Super User](http://superuser.com/q/729590), not meta.Math.

Comment: I reinstalled the system after format all hard and faild to load ltaex at the site and gave me "Mathematics Stack Exchange requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load."
also that happen at the computer of my friend

Comment: @hammood Does MathJax work on the [test page](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/tex-samples/)?

Comment: yes it work ......

Comment: @hammood OK, what does the JavaScript console say now, when you open it on Math.SE page?

Comment: it work at every site also at stackexchange site which provide latex but at math stack stackexchange dosent work

Comment: GET http://mathjax-cdn.storage.googleapis.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full 403 (Forbidden) sequence-of-a-n-frac12n:50
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery.min.js:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined

Comment: and for what time ? day ? 2 ? less or more in your opinion ?

Comment: thank you alot and I also hope to get a quick response :)

Comment: @hammood When you click the link http://mathjax-cdn.storage.googleapis.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js  do you get an error message, or the code with "Copyright (c) 2009-2013 The MathJax Consortium" ?

Comment: I get :This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied.</Message>
<Details>
We're sorry, but this service is not available in your country
</Details>
</Error>

Comment: @hammood What country are you in?

Comment: syria .......... but iam user from 1 year and this is the first time that happen with me

Comment: @hammood That's the thing: as I wrote  in my explanation, the site recently switched to loading MathJaX from Google Cloud Storage. Apparently, Google Cloud Storage is blocked in Syria. I'll try to see if a solution can be found.

Comment: yes please if you can and thank you^99 :)

Comment: @hammood One possibility is to use the [userscript by Davide Cervone](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12424/127096); it detects that MathJax failed to load, and then loads it from different CDN. Try it... the script is intended for FireFox, I am not sure if Chrome will allow its installation for security reasons.

Comment: @hammood we were testing the new CDN that the MathJax folks are exploring here on math to check for performance and uncover issues like this. They are aware of the issue and we'll see how they want to proceed. For now we have reverted to the old CDN since we absolutely don't want to serve broken pages.

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills: It should work in Chrome too, if you drag-and-drop it into the `chrome:extensions` page (or use Tampermonkey).

Comment: thanks for every one ,it works after I installed userscript by Davide Cervone :)

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills thanks alot for the time you give it to me :)